# list-style-type: none; does not convert from epub to mobi

Tags: epub, conversion, mobi

I have a book written in epub, and have some lines written with ul style. The styles.css includes the following:

```
ul.Q {
margin-left: 0.0em;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 0.8em;
}

li.Q {
text-indent: -2em;
margin-left: 2.5em;
margin-top: 0.0em;
}
```

The main document has a reference to this in the header:

```
<link href="../Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and the following lines:

```
<ul class="Q">
<li class="Q">“There is no one righteous;</li>
<li class="Q">no, not one.</li>
</ul>
```

In epub this works as expected. Here is a screenshot from Sigil:

[image: epub indentation screenshot]

Now, if I upload the epub to KDP much of the other formatting does not survive the conversion. So I converted it to .mobi using Calibre and uploaded that. It seems to work perfectly everywhere else, except that here the screenshot looks like this:

[image: mobi indentation screenshot]

Note the bullet points. This is a screenshot from KDP's online previewer. On my Kindle, it has the same issue. For some reason, .mobi is not respecting the list-style-type: none.

I have run my stylesheet through an online checker and there are no flaws. And other elements of the style sheet are working in this same chapter, so I know it is linked correctly.

So the question is: how do you make .mobi respect the list-style-type: none? Or is there a different workaround?

---

Update: according to [this forum](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=126747) mobi does not support list styles. So what workarounds  do people do for this? I guess the right thing (since I don't want the bullets) is just to use a div?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At our shop we create a separate set of EPUB source files to convert to MOBI, and we perform a bunch of automated hacks on them before zipping and converting so the eventual MOBI file will be formatted correctly. In the case of list-style-type: none, our hack is to replace the li with a p and the ul with a div.